# Android: regex throws PatternSyntaxException when runs on real device but not on Unit test

Tags: android, regex

I'm working on Android project and I want to remove/replace a certain param inside my url, i.e

> params=12143

so I wrote a regex to evaluate url

`(?<=[?&])?params=(.*?)(&|$)`

It works perfectly on online testing tool, I also wrote unit test for it and it passed without any problem. Sample to test below

> https://example.com/xyz --> no match
>
> https://example.com/xyz?**params=123456** --> matched
>
> https://example.com/xyz?another=124&**params=123456** --> matched
>
> https://example.com/xyz?another=124&**params=123456**&yetanother=2425 --> matched

And then I tested it on real device, Android throwed PatternSyntaxException with message

> Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 10 (?<=[?&])?params=(.*?)(&|$)

Found out the optional **?** right before **params** cause the exception. I removed it and it works on both unit test and real device.

So here is my question: Why my regex fails? And only on real device but not unit test or online tools?

Comment: There is no sense adding quantifiers after lookarounds since they are non-consuming patterns. It causes undefined behavior, and each regex implementation handles that their own way. So, in Android regex that uses ICU regex library, it is forbidden. Java, PCRE, .NET, Onigmo (Ruby) do not throw any exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your special char `?` like this:

```
(?<=[?&])\\?params=(.*?)(&|$)
```